# Change Slicer "Name to use in formulas"

Tags: excel, slicers

I have create some slicers connected on a pivot table and now i want to change their "Name to use in formulas".

[image]

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 6):

How to Change Slicer “Name to use in formulas”

1. Formulas
2. Name Manager
3. Select the slicer you want
4. Press Edit

Answer (score 0):

I think what he meant is to be able to get the slicer name created with the unique number and use it in macro formula and not do it manually which is also what I'm looking for.  Can we just add another name instead of that unique number?

A slicer name is given the number 1, 2, 3 after Slicer_NameofField_# <<

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer